# PC boots on second try without pushing the power button

Tags: bios, grub

It started a year ago, when I click the power button, the BIOS logo (manufacturer) appears, then pc turns off, after a second it turns on again, this time it boots normally. Tried to search for the issue, but couldn't find similar problems.

I don't click the power button for the second time, it is turning off and on by itself. It doesn't boot to the grub menu at the first time, just reboots itself and then boots to grub. The manufacturer logo is displayed both times.

I opened and cleaned pc 2 days ago, replaced the thermal paste just in case, it is still same. This is happening for 1 year already.

Comment: Your BIOS battery may be cause. On first start it automatically configures itself and saves the new config which causes the PC to turn off and on again to fully apply the new config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Robert suggested, it was due to the bios battery. After replacing the battery, it started to boot normally as before without any reboots between.